# Shipping stack data in and out of closures

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, rust

I have a C function that for various C reasons can only be called from certain kinds of threads.  I'm trying to call this function from Rust.

The idea that I had was to ship the input data onto the "right" thread, call the C function on that thread, and then wait on the thread using a semaphore before shipping its return value back out.

The thread isn't used for concurrency; it's really a rather synchronous execution flow.  It's simply that the C function is persnickety about how it can be used.

This was my attempt:

```
use std::thread::Thread;

struct Foo {
    x: std::sync::Semaphore,
}

//Not the real C function, of course.
fn my_great_c_function(i: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("{}",i);
    return 12;
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {
        self.x = std::sync::Semaphore::new(0);
        let input : i32 = 5;
        let mut output : i32 = 10;
        Thread::spawn(|:| {
            //call out to our C function that only likes some threads
            output = my_great_c_function(input);
            self.x.release(); //our work is done; the parent thread can continue
        });
        self.x.acquire(); //wait for child thread to be done interacting with environment
        println!("{}",input); //check input
        println!("{}",output); //check output
    }

}
```

The Rust compiler outputs a whole page of errors explaining that it `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements`.

From what I can piece together I think the compiler is concerned that the closure may outlive the stack frame, and the closure's references to `input` and `output` may get blown away while the closure is still using them (this is, I suspect, the meaning of `lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime`).  But in fact, the semaphore is used to keep the stack frame alive until the closure finishes, so that shouldn't happen.

Is there some way to calm the compiler?  Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread::spawn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.spawn) is defined thus:

```
fn spawn<F>(f: F) -> Thread where F: FnOnce(), F: Send + 'static
```

The function you are passing it must own all its data (`'static` requires this). You, however, are trying to do something with `self` which is definitely not `'static`. Remember, Rust cares about safety; threads are not allowed to mess with other threads’ data: you cannot access an object on more than one thread.

What you want is actually easier than what you were trying: use [`Thread::scoped`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.scoped):

```
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {
        let input = 5i32;
        let output = Thread::scoped(|:| {
            my_great_c_function(input)
        }).join().unwrap();
        println!("{}", input);
        println!("{}", output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got `core::result::Result<i32, Box<core::any::Any + Send>>` does not implement any method in scope named `unwrap`.  I tried to use .ok().unwrap() instead and got more `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements.`